# F11 key changed functionality

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

<kbd>F11</kbd> on my Mac used to show Desktop. Something changed in my function keys and I cannot figure out what. The <kbd>F11</kbd> key now decreases volume on my speaker, and the only way to see my Desktop is to now use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>. This is very annoying.

My keyboard shortcut under System Preferences shows that <kbd>F11</kbd> (by itself) is supposed to show Desktop.

The <kbd>F12</kbd> key used to be set to a particular function in Adobe InDesign but is no longer working either. I didn't knowingly change my keyboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Mac do you use? A MacBook? Do you use non-Apple Keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Preferences app → Keyboard → Keyboard and check Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.

[image]

Comment: "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" was already selected. ALL of my F key functions now require me to hold down the fn key at the same time to make them work

Comment: pages and pages of comments say to do that. I came to this site hoping for something a little more precise

Comment: @DavidRPosey You should have mentioned that in your question that you have already tried it and it didn't work. You need to describe your problem in more detail along with everything that you have already tried.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me.  Not sure why but disconnect, then reconnect your external keyboard to fix the issue.